# Как получить почту с mail.ru

Tags: php, mail.ru

Как подключиться к ящику на `mail.ru` и получать от туда почту?
`imap_open` возвращает ошибку:

> Couldn't open stream

Пробовал разные варианты:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.mail.ru:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "логин", "пароль");
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.mail.ru:143/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "логин", "пароль");
$mbox = imap_open("{pop.mail.ru:110}INBOX", "логин", "пароль");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
imap_open("{imap.mail.ru:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "логин", "пароль");
```

SSL же [на 993](https://help.mail.ru/mail-help/mailer/popsmtp) порту.

Comment: Не работает. это тоже пробовал
502 Bad Gateway

The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

Comment: 502 - это ни о чём. На чём конкретно падает? Посмотрите в логах, запустите с консоли. У меня нет учётки mail.ru, приведённый вызов закономерно отвечает "Please specify user/password". Кстати, а mailru поддержку imap не надо предварительно включать в профиле?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $stream = imap_open('{imap.mail.ru:993/imap/ssl}', 'тут логин@mail.ru', 'тут пароль') or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());;


  if ($stream) { $n=1; $st = imap_fetchstructure($stream, $n);
  if (!empty($st->parts)) {
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($st->parts); $i < $j; $i++){
      $part = $st->parts[$i];
        if ($part->subtype == 'PLAIN') {
          $body = imap_fetchbody($stream, $n, $i+1);                                                                                                                                                                   
        } else {
          $body = imap_body($stream, $n);                                                                                                  
          echo('$body: '.imap_body($stream, 1));
        }
      }
    }
  imap_close($stream);
?>
```